# How to expose C++ unions to Lua

Tags: c++, lua, unions

For a project I'm working on, I need to expose some C++ classes in another library to Lua. Unfortunately, one of the most important classes in this library has lots of Unions and Enums ([the sf::Event class from SFML](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Window/Event.hpp)), and from a [quick Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=c%20lua%20expose%20unions&es_th=1) I've discovered there is nothing on exposing C++ Unions to Lua. I don't mind if it's being exposed with the Lua/C API, with a library or with a binding generator, as long as it works. But, I'd prefer not to use a binding generator, because I want to be able to create an object in C++, then expose that instance of the object to Lua (unless that's possible with a binding generator)

Comment: How about expose that class with some setter and getter?

Comment: @Calvin In my case (exposing sf::Event), that's a very messy solution because it involves lots of getters with lots of if statements. I've also had issues with getters for sf::Event and the library I'm using. But I'll look into trying it with another library/with the Lua/C API.

Comment: You've been stuck on this for a while. Have you learned the C API yet? Do you know Lua metatables well? It's relatively straightforward if you understand how userdata and metatables work. Here's a [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484773/call-c-functions-in-an-active-program-from-lua/31486050#31486050).

Comment: @Mud I understand the Lua C API and Lua metatables, I'm just not sure if C++ unions would create any problems (I've never used unions in my own classes, the template library I was previously using didn't work properly when using getters to access the union, and the question got one comment in the 4 days it's been open, indicating the question either has some difficulty, or SO is overly saturated and requires a bounty to get an answer >:( )

Comment: @Orfby Your previous question (nearly a month ago) was about LuaBridge and/or binding libraries. A binding library might not support unions, but it's a non-issue for the C API. Your C++ object is exposed as a userdata. That userdata exposes fields like "size" and "text" via an __index metamethod. That they're in a union is totally irrelevant. Those fields return objects like SizeEvent, which is just more userdata, each with their own metatables. If you don't know what that means, you'll want to learn the C API and/or metatables better than you do now.

Answer (score 1):

For registering C/C++ functions you need to first make your function look like a standard C function pattern which Lua provides:

```
extern "C" int MyFunc(lua_State* L)
{
    int a = lua_tointeger(L, 1); // First argument
    int b = lua_tointeger(L, 2); // Second argument
    int result = a + b;

    lua_pushinteger(L, result);

    return 1; // Count of returned values
}
```

Every function that needs to be registered in Lua should follow this pattern. Return type of `int` , single parameter of `lua_State* L`. And count of returned values.
Then, you need to register it in Lua's register table so you can expose it to your script's context:

```
lua_register(L, "MyFunc", MyFunc);
```

For registering simple variables you can write this:

```
lua_pushinteger(L, 10);
lua_setglobal(L, "MyVar");
```

After that, you're able to call your function from a Lua script. Keep in mind that you should register all of your objects before running any script with that specific Lua state that you've used to register them.

In Lua:

```
print(MyFunc(10, MyVar))
```

Result:

20

I guess this could help you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use boost::variant rather than a union, you could try using my [LuaCast](https://github.com/Alicemargatroid/lua_cast) library.

I'll try to add unions as a base type as well.

Comment: The OP is exposing code from a different library to Lua: it is unlikely they will have the ability to modify the 3rd party library.

Comment: @Yakk That's why they need to generate a wrapper